# Pushing new Fragment with supportFragmentManager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am inside `onBindViewHolder` and i want to **show a new Fragment** in `holder.view.setOnClickListener { }`

I'm passing the current fragment in my Adapter:

```kotlin
class HomeAdapter(val fragment: Fragment?) : RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
```

if i try to use `supportFragmentManager` **nothing** happens if i tap a row:

```kotlin
fragment
  .requireActivity()
  .supportFragmentManager
  .beginTransaction()
  .add(R.id.main_fragment, GalleryFragment())
  .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
  .addToBackStack("HomeFragment")
  .commit()
```

However if i use the **deprecated** one it works:

```kotlin
fragment
  .requireFragmentManager()
  .beginTransaction()
  .replace(R.id.main_fragment, GalleryFragment())
  .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
  .addToBackStack("HomeFragment")
  .commit()
```

I don't want to use the deprecated one. Is there a way to fix this?

Edit:

This is my class where i call `onClickListener`:

```kotlin
class DhikrHomeAdapter(val fragment: Fragment?, val data: Array<PreviewDhikr>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<DhikrHomeAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return data.size
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(fragment?.requireContext())
        val cell = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dhikr_row, parent, false)

        return ViewHolder(cell)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val cell = holder.view

        val currentDhikr = data[position]
        cell.dhikrType.text = currentDhikr.dhikrType.rawValue
        val img = fragment?.requireContext()?.resources!!.getIdentifier(currentDhikr.previewImage, "drawable", fragment.requireContext().packageName)
        cell.backgroundImage.setImageResource(img)

        cell.setOnClickListener {
            fragment
                .requireFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.main_fragment, DhikrFragment(currentDhikr))
                .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                .addToBackStack("HomeFragment")
                .commit()
        }
    }

    class ViewHolder(val view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)
}
```

Comment: Why are you passing fragment in construction of adapter? it isn't required. Simply create new Fragment in onclickListener.

Comment: I'm new to android programming please give me an example. @BhoomiVaghasiya

Comment: check out my answer below

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass `Context` in adapter construction

```
class HomeAdapter(val context: Context?) : RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeAdapter.ViewHolder>() {...}
```

Wherever you want to add new fragment, add this code:

```
FragmentManager fm = ((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
fm.beginTransaction()
  .add(R.id.main_fragment, new GalleryFragment())
  .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
  .addToBackStack("GallaryFragment")
  .commit();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nothing happens if i tap the row.

Comment: Please put your all important code here then and then I can  help you

Comment: Check the question again please @BhoomiVaghasiya

Comment: it should not the cell.onclicklistener

Comment: what else?? Please provide a valid code. @BhoomiVaghasiya

Answer (score 0):

**in AndroidStudio 4.0.1 and Kotlin
to display Name,Detail,ItemImage**

**first edit your onBindViewHolder as follows:**

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ListViewHolder, position: Int) {
 
    holder.item_row_name.text = items[position].Name

    holder.item_row_detail.text = items[position].Detail

    Glide.with(context)
        .load(items[position].ItemImage)
        .into(holder.item_row_image)


   holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {

        
       val fragmentManager = (context as FragmentActivity).supportFragmentManager

       if(position==0){
           val buildFragment = BuildFragment()
           fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment, buildFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit()

       }
       if(position==1){
           val carFragment = CarFragment()
           fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment, carFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit()

       }
   }


}
```

**second in your activity add Farmelayout ,,where you need to display your Fragment**

```
 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

**I hope this help you**